# How to make text fade out

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have an HTML form, and on a button click, javascript processes it, and text appears below the button, saying "form sent". I would like to make this text fade away after a few seconds, say around five. I am using this method to write the text in the first place:

```
document.getElementById('sent_box').innerHTML='form sent.';
```

The HTML  box being written to looks like this:

```
<div id='sent_box'></div>
```

with this styling:

```
#sent_box{
height: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;
}
```

How would I be able to make the text fade out after ten seconds?

**Note that I need a Vanilla Javascript solution to this. NO JQuery answers, please.**

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you can add a class with ```opacity: 0;``` and add css3 transitions

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Without jQuery, the easiest method for this would probably be to setup a CSS3 animation to fade out the element, and then trigger it with JavaScript after a set time. [Here's an article about doing that](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-transitions-javascript/) (the article uses jQuery but the concepts can be applied without it).

Comment: @oxguy3 unfortunately, that articls uses JQuery, which I specifically DID NOT ask for.

Comment: @Mr.Chameleon And as I said, I linked to that site because it describes the basic methodology for how to achieve the result you want. You won't be able to copy paste that code into your website, but you should be able to write vanilla JS that achieves the same thing based on that article.

Comment: @Mr.Chameleon the answer that I've provided is a vanilla JS code, not a JQuery one, you can scroll down to find out that it's actually a vanilla JS code in the link that I've put in my answer.. Btw , you should check the "animations" checkbox to get that code.

Comment: @ayadibaha what I mean by Vanilla JS is just regular Javascript, no JQuery or any of that. I didn't mean a library called Vanilla JS

Comment: @Mr.Chameleon : So you should specify that it's just JS , you don't have to say Vanilla JS. I'll edit my answer so it'll be a pure JS solution then.

Comment: @ayadibaha when someone says vanilla javascript, they  mean just regular javascript. It's a pretty commonly used term. Make sure you understand a question before you answer it.

Comment: Thanks for the information @Mr.Chameleon , I just didn't saw anybody asking a question and refering to JS by that before. So it's a brand new information for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with pure JS.

I've added comments for each line of the JS so you can understand and learn for future reference.

```js
setTimeout(function() { // start a delay
  var fade = document.getElementById("fade"); // get required element
  fade.style.opacity = 1; // set opacity for the element to 1
  var timerId = setInterval(function() { // start interval loop
    var opacity = fade.style.opacity; // get current opacity
    if (opacity == 0) { // check if its 0 yet
      clearInterval(timerId); // if so, exit from interval loop
    } else {
      fade.style.opacity = opacity - 0.05; // else remove 0.05 from opacity
    }
  }, 100); // run every 0.1 second
}, 5000); // wait to run after 5 seconds
```

```html
<div id="fade">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler option.

The CSS:

```
<style>
#objecttofade{
             color: white;
             opacity: 1;             //set opacity to 1 so it will be fully visible
             transition: all 0.25s; //you can change the duration of the transition
             }
<style>
```

JS:

```
<script> function change(){                        //assign onload or onclick
    document.getElementById('p1').style.opacity = "0";}//changes opacity to 0
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not use css 3. Follow this link to jsfiddle for an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/nZjEL/179/

```
 @-webkit-keyframes fade-out {
0% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: scale(1);}
85% {opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);}
100% {-webkit-transform: scale(.1); opacity: 0;}
}

.fade-out {
    -webkit-animation: fade-out .5s ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.fade-out.one {-webkit-animation-delay: .5s;}
.fade-out.two {-webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;}
.fade-out.three {-webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;}
.fade-out.four {-webkit-animation-delay: 5.5s;}
```

Comment: OP still needs javascript...where is that?

Comment: Why are you using webkit prefixed properties? While there are acceptable reasons for doing so, why are you using **only** webkit prefixed properties?

Comment: The JSFIDDLE does nothing. The div just sits there, and does nothing.

Comment: it's unbelieveable how many people write an answer without reading the whole question.